# Running "at" command on Windows XP - Why the job is not executed?

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks, at-job

On Windows XP I'm trying to add a job like this:

```
at 17:07 /every:s dir
```

I expect `dir` to be executed every Saturday at 17:07, however I don't see anything happens in the command line window.

Here is the log:

```
D:\temp>at 17:07 /every:s dir
Added a new job with job ID = 1

D:\temp>time/t
05:06 PM

D:\temp>date/t
Sat 10/02/2010

D:\temp>at
Status ID   Day                     Time          Command Line
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error   1   Each S                  5:07 PM       dir

D:\temp>time/t
05:08 PM

D:\temp>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: You can probably look in the computer's event log to see exactly what the error is.
Also, `dir` is a command that's "inside" `cmd`, the command interpreter - so you might have to run `cmd /c dir` to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the `cmd /c` explanation ! You should have posted it as an answer so I could accept it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Task Scheduler service runs `at` commands in the background.  You should not expect to see anything just because you happen to have a console open.  A simple way to test that it runs is to write to a log file.  You will likely want to wrap this in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `/interactive` parameter in order for the output to be visible.

Comment: `/interactive` means that the command can interact with GUI windows even though services normally can not.  It does not mean that output will get printed to an open console.  See also [Applications Started with AT Are Not Interactive](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121562).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that you need to explicitly launch md.exe as well :`cmd /c dir `. Microsoft have a suitable example here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/at.mspx?mfr=true

  (btw, Other than writing a cutom application I don;t think there is any way to hook into an already open console window)